# Python-Prime number checker-product of primes

Tags: python, primes

I wrote the following code to check for whether a number is prime. While there are more efficient ways to do this, I did notice that while this works for the largest of the primes, it breaks for every product of primes. So, while it correctly identifies 13 and 17 as primes, it also identifies 91 (13 × 7) as prime. Any ideas why?

```
def checkifprime(numtocheck):
    for x in range(2,numtocheck):
        if(numtocheck % x == 0):
            return False
        return True

answer = checkifprime(91)
print (answer)
```

Comment: you only need to check numbers up to the (~square root +1) of a given number.

Comment: Check for an even number outside your loop, and then you only have to check odd numbers: 3, 5, 7, 9 ... in your loop.  As corn3lius says, you can stop checking once you have reached the square root of the number.

Answer (score 5):

`return True` is indented too far; it’s inside the loop and causes the function to exit on the first iteration, so your function really only checks whether a number is odd.

```
def checkifprime(numtocheck):
    for x in range(2, numtocheck):
        if numtocheck % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program never gets farther than the first iteration.  What you effectively have is an even-or-oddness checker.  The program always returns in the first iteration of the loop.  You are returning `True` too early.

Answer (score 2):

The `return True` statement isn't indented properly - you've placed it inside the `for` loop. So, the loop starts with `2`, and if the number is odd it doesn't enter the `if` and then returns `True`. You should place this statement **after** the `for` loop. Only once the loop is exhausted, if you didn't find any appropriate divisor, can you return that this number is a prime:

```
def checkifprime(numtocheck):
    for x in range(2,numtocheck):
        if(numtocheck % x == 0):
            return False
    return True # Note the indendation
```