# The prime function is not returning correct result

Tags: python, primes

I wrote a piece of code to check whether a number is a prime or not. It works in Powershell, but won't work on the online submission platform.

I have re-read how to define whther a number is prime and I can't find anything else that I might have missed in my code.

```
x = int(input('Please enter a number: '))

if x > 1:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
            break
        else:
            print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')
            break
else:
    print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
```

Should print out whether a number is prime or not.

Comment: On what test case does it not work?

Comment: Your condition inside the loop always breaks the loop on its first iteration. Start from fixing this.

Comment: *won't work on the online submission platform.* please provide more details on it. What's the error message you're getting or wrong output

Comment: This code doesn't work at all. You can't know whether a number is prime until you've tried all the possible prime factors. Not just one of them.

Comment: Think the algorithm through. Do you need a loop at all?

Comment: Also, you can just check up to square root of x instead of x - 1

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar it says a number is a prime when it's not. I can't see the specific case because the website generates its own number to test my function.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Yes, he does need a loop. Your point?

Comment: Your code always prints and breaks after checking `x % 2`. Lose the `break` statements, and print the conclusion only after the loop is over.

Comment: @YokoKoko Have you considered testing your code *yourself?*

Comment: for i in range(2,x + 1)
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (x % i) == 0:
               print("not a prime")
               break
       else:
           print("It's optimus prime",num)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python-Prime number checker-product of primes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312487/python-prime-number-checker-product-of-primes)

Comment: I wanted to use this piece of code because I am learning and I came up with it myself. I don't want to copy the code of someone else; just want to know where I went wrong and correct it myself @user207421

Comment: Well you can either use this code or learn the right way to do it. Not both at the same time.

Comment: @user207421 Not explicit `for` statement. I guess a more Pythonic way would be:
`
x = int(input('Please enter a number: '));
y = range(2,x);
z = map(lambda a: divmod(x,a)[1],y);
print("Even") if all(z) else print("Not Even")
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = int(input('Please enter a number: '))

if x > 1:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
            break
    else:
        print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')

else:
    print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
```

This correction worked!

Comment: You don't need `if x > 1:` because the the `range` generator would generate nothing if the given input number is not greater than `2`, and would therefore force the loop to finish immediately and go into the `else` block to determine that it is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for-else` construct so that a prime number is only determined when the loop finishes without breaking due to finding a divisor. Also, you only need to iterate up to the square root of the input number when looking for a divisor:

```
x = int(input('Please enter a number: '))

for i in range(2, int(x ** .5) + 1):
    if x % i == 0:
        print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
        break
else:
    print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you have to remove the innermost else clause.

Think in the case that x = 9, for example. Control flow will enter the for clause, starting with i=2. It will test if x % i == 0, that is, if x is divisible by i. It isn't. Then you go to the else clause. Prints that "The number you inputted is a prime number" and breaks, ending the for loop. That is not what you want.

You only conclude that the number is prime after looking if it is divisible by all of the i's. That is, you want the code concluding the number is prime (the print("The number you inputted is a prime number")) to be outside the for loop.

Some tweaks are needed overall. Here is a working solution:

```
x = int(input('Please enter a number: '))

if x > 1:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
            break
    if i==x-1:
            print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')
else:
    print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Here's a solution modeled after the way you tried the code. Note that sometimes, if you copy a code from certain websites, you could run into code formatting issues/problems with indentation. For example, when I copied a similar code-block from [programiz.com: prime-number](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number) it repeatedly returned indentation error. The only way I could get around that is hand typing the code logic.

Perhaps one could try fixing this by copy pasting the code into a plain-text-editor (like notepad) and then copy-pasting that into the IDE you are using.

```py
def is_prime(num):

    isprime = False
    # prime numbers are greater than 1
    if (num>1):
        for i in range(2,num):
            # check if divisible by any number
            # other than itself and 1
            if (num % i) == 0:
                isprime = False
                break
            # Not divisible by any number 
            # other than itself and 1
            else:
                isprime = True
    # numbers 0 and 1 are not prime numbers
    else:
        isprime = False

    return isprime

is_prime(31), is_prime(42)
```

**Output**:

```
(True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a more pythonic way:

```
x = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
if x<2:
    print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
elif x==2:
    print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')
else:
    y = range(2,x)
    mod = map(lambda a:divmod(x,a)[1],y)
    if all(mod):
        print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')
    else:
        print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
```

Answer (score -2):

What about removing that else statement. You really need to check all numbers 2 ... (k-1)

```
x = int(input('Please enter a number: '))

if x > 1:
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2, x - 1):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
    if is_prime:
        print('The number you inputted is a prime number.')
    else:
        print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')

else:
    print('The number you inputted is not a prime number.')
```

Comment: It will print `... not a prime number ` followed by `prime number` for non-prime numbers